# Qual a melhor forma de relacionar esta entidade

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jpa

na minha aplicação eu tenho uma entidade usuário que se relaciona de muitos pra muitos com a entidade cursos (um usuário pode se matricular em muitos cursos e um curso pode ter vários usuários)
E a entidade cursos se relaciona de um para muitos com a entidade aula (um curso tem varias aulas, mas uma aula só tem um curso)

Estou fazendo a minha aplicação com spring boot e para eu dizer que o usuario se matriculou em um curso eu so tenho que fazer:

```
usuario.getCursos().add(curso)
curso.getUsuario().add(usuario)
usuarioRepository.save(usuario)
```

ao relacionar um curso ao usuário posso dizer que ele se matriculou no curso. Mas como relacionar o usuário a uma aula para saber por exemplo quais aulas ele concluiu? eu posso aproveitar este relacionamento do usuario muitoParaMuitos curso umParaMuitos aula ou tenho que criar um relacionamento muitos para muitos de usuario com aula?

Aqui vai um pequeno exemplo das entidades para exemplificar melhor como esta o relacionamento:

```
@Entity
public class Usuario{

private long id;
private String nome;
private String senha;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = “usuariosMatriculados”, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable
private List cursosMatriculados;

//getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Curso{

private long id;
private String nomeCurso;
private String descricaoCurso;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = “cursosMatriculados”, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable
private List usuariosMatriculados;
@OnetoMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List aulas;
//getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Aula{

private long id;
private String nomeAula;
private String conteudoAula;
@ManyToOne(mappedBy = “aulas”, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable
private Curso curso;
//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que o melhor caso é ter uma relação de muitos para muitos entre Usuário e Aula. Entendo que esta relação seja independente do Curso.

Desta forma, você teria:

```
class Usuario {

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Curso> cursos;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Aula> aulas;

}

class Aula {

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Usuario> usuario;

    @ManyToOne
    private Curso curso;

}

class Curso {

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Usuario> usuario;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Aula> aulas;

}
```

Minha recomendação ainda seria não usar `@ManyToMany`. Eu sugiro mapear a tabela intermediária, pois fica menos "mágico" e eventualmente você sentirá a necessidade de adicionar informações nesta tabela de relacionamento. Acabo ficando mais verboso, mas acho que valerá a pena.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou pesquisar como faz para usar uma tabela intermediaria.